# sqlite3 .read command not working with unicode script

Tags: sql, cmd, sqlite

I used command `.read script.sql` (of command line tool sqlite3.exe that I've downloaded from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to import data to an existing database sqlite.
File script.sql was saved with notepad++ in encoding **UTF8 without BOM**, has content like this:

```
INSERT INTO "table1" VALUES('Các con cáo nâu nhanh chóng nhảy chó lười biếng');
INSERT INTO "table1" VALUES('速い茶色のキツネは、のろまなイヌに飛びかかっ');
INSERT INTO "table1" VALUES('빠른 갈색 여우가 게으른 개 점프');
```

But after I ran above command, data was convert to ansii, like this:

```
CÃ¡c con cÃ¡o nÃ¢u nhanh chÃ³ng nháº£y chÃ³ lÆ°á»i biáº¿ng
é€Ÿã„èŒ¶è‰²ã®ã‚­ãƒ„ãƒã¯ã€ã®ã‚ã¾ãªã‚¤ãƒŒã«é£›ã³ã‹ã‹ã£
ë¹ ë¥¸ ê°ˆìƒ‰ ì—¬ìš°ê°€ ê²Œìœ¼ë¥¸ ê°œ ì í”„
```

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: When running `sqlite3.exe` in the Windows console, UTF-8 keyboard input or screen output is not handled correctly.

Comment: @CL. I did not enter unicode character directly into console. I just ran `.read script.sql`. I checked data by tool SQLite Expert, not by output to console screen.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(Column1) FROM ...` for the first row?

Comment: @CL. the hex is 43C383C2A16320636F6E2063C383C2A16F206EC383C2A275206E68616E68206368C383C2B36E67206E68C3A1C2BAC2A379206368C383C2B3206CC386C2B0C3A1C2BBC29D69206269C3A1C2BAC2BF6E67.
This is my sample, you can download check it http://www.mediafire.com/download/xc1kc744dbjcyf5

Comment: I guess your database data are not converted; the problem lays in _displaying_ them  in Windows console.  Change the codepage to UTF-8 by executing `chcp 65001` _before_ running `sqlite3.exe`.

Comment: I did attached my sample above, you may want to check it out in order to know if actually convert or not, So please don't guess!
I absolutely have never displayed any data to windows console in order to check imported data.
I just ran only two command with windows console:
1 `sqlite3.exe sample.db`
2 `.read script.sql`
That's it.

Comment: @CL. I did executed `chcp 65001` but it's not better.

Comment: @JosefZ You are wrong; the output shows correctly what is in the database. Apparently, the .sql file is not encoded correctly.

Comment: The .sql was generate by `.dump` command. So how correctly is the .sql encoded?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code, this is a bug in the sqlite3 tool. On Windows in interactive mode it unconditionally converts all input from ANSI to UTF-8, even from file.

To fix this issue line 488 of `shell.c` (an amalgamation, version 3.11.1) can be changed to:

```
if( stdin_is_interactive && in == stdin){
```

Just checked it and fixed my similar issue.